# Image and button placed by percentage but are cropped when I resize the window

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to make my application responsive.
For that, the first thing I did was placing my buttons and logo by using percentages instead of pixels.

The problem is that when I resize my window to a smaller one, the buttons and logo are moving but they are also cropped on the side like this:

*Here is what the button looks like before resizing:*

[image]

*And here is what it looks like after resizing to a smaller one:*

[image]

How can I make it move but still appear in its entirety ?

Here is my CSS for this button:

```
#next-step{
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    left:88%
}
```

Comment: remove `top` and `left` instead use `right: 2rem` and `bottom: 2rem`. You can change values.

Comment: Eventhough given in %, it will overlap, because, the position will be same. Only the size will be reduced. So instead, you need to write media query to specify how you want it to behave in smaller screens. Say giving 100% width to both and align them one after another,

Comment: The top-left corner position is now relative to the window size, but the button's size is still an absolute value. Use the bottom-right corner instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the CSS as follows:

```
#next-step{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1em;
    right: 1em;
}
```

By using bottom and right instead of top and left, the reference will be the bottom right corner of your container. This way your button will never crop. You can play with the values to adjust the position of the button as you like.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the position values to bottom and right might help you out. You could try this CSS code and maybe adjust the percentage values to your liking:

```
#next-step{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    right: 12%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to the way you're positioning the element.

```
#next-step{
    position: absolute;
    top: 90%;
    left:88%
}
```

Is positioning the button based on the top-left corner.

If you were to instead use:

```
#next-step{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    right:12%
}
```

It'll set the position to a similar place on-screen, but based on the bottom-right corner (you'll need to fine tune the numbers).

However, one thing to note: when using percentages, once you get below a certain screen size it can get messy, so it'd be worth looking at media queries too.